# Why specialization based on enable_if is not picked up by compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, enable-if

I'd like to specialize class for some type of classes, for example based on std::is_arithmetic. Although compiler doesn't "see" my specialization based on "enable_if" and chooses principle/main template. Could you please help me with this... 
Below is snippet of code and output after compiling with g++ 4.8

```
#include < iostream >  
#include < type_traits >  
#include < string >  

template < typename T1, typename T2 = void >  
struct TestT  
{  
    static const bool is_int = false;  
    static const bool is_str = false;  
};

template < typename T>  
struct TestT < T,  
       std::enable_if< std::is_arithmetic<t>::value, T >::type >  
{  
    static const bool is_int = true;  
    static const bool is_str = false;  
};  

template < typename T>
struct TestT < std::string, T >  
{  
    static const bool is_int = false;  
    static const bool is_str = true;  
};  

class enum TestE  
{  
    Last  
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{
    std::cout << "Enum is_int: " << TestT<TestE>::is_int  
              << ", is_str: " << TestT<TestE>::is_str << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "string is_int: " << TestT<std::string>::is_int  
              << ", is_str: " << TestT<std::string>::is_str << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "int is_int: " << TestT<int>::is_int  
              << ", is_str: " << TestT<int>::is_str << std::endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Output of above is:

> `Enum is_int: 0, is_str: 0`   // Expected
>   `string is_int: 0, is_str: 1` // Expected
>   `int is_int: 0, is_str: 0`    // Not expected

I really would appreciate for any help, and thank you in advance

Comment: please post some code that compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leave the second parameter (the type aliased by `::type`) either unspecified or `void` so that it matches the primary template's default argument:

```c++
struct TestT<T,  
       std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
```

You also need `typename` before the `std::enable_if` statement, or use `std::enable_if_t` (and leave out `::type`):

```c++
struct TestT<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
```

Same goes for the second specialization:

```c++
template<>
struct TestT<std::string>  
{  
    static const bool is_int = false;  
    static const bool is_str = true;  
};
```

And lastly, within this specialization, `is_int` should be set to `true`:

```c++
template<typename T>  
struct TestT<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>  
{  
    static const bool is_int = true;  
    static const bool is_str = false;  
};
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1675935d0719125)</kbd>

A better version might be to keep a single specialization and use `std::is_same` to test for `int` and a type trait to test for strings:

```c++
template<class T>struct is_string:std::false_type{};
template<>struct is_string<std::string>:std::true_type{};
template<std::size_t N>struct is_string<char const(&)[N]>:std::true_type{};
template<>struct is_string<char const*>:std::true_type{};
template<>struct is_string<char const*const>:std::true_type{};
template<>struct is_string<char const*volatile>:std::true_type{};
// on and on...

template<typename T>  
struct TestT  
{  
    static const bool is_int = std::is_same<T, int>();  
    static const bool is_str = is_string<T>();  
};
```

Comment: I'm clicking on check link, although could you please explain why second parameter has to match to primary template. If to look at second specialization, for std::string, second parameter doesn't match but it works  for string

Comment: @Yurishd That was an oversight on my part, the specialization for `std::string` should either have `void` or an empty second parameter in the specialization. The reason it works is because the template is more specialized than the primary template (first parameter takes `std::string`, second parameter takes anything). Therefore it is chosen. The correct code should be: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1675935d0719125